# Hidden button, does not work on the first click after appeared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, hidden

I have two buttons,
One will plot data, second will download data.
Only if this plot has data i will show excel download button.
this part works fine, but my first click on second button never works, 
Thank you for your help.

in html:

```
<button id='btn-plot' class='btn-dark'>Plot</button>
<button id='btn-xls' class='btn-dark' hidden='hidden'>Excel</button>
```

in js:

```
$('#btn-plot').on('click', function(lista) {

        var lista = data['lista'].toString()
        if (lista.length != 0) {
                document.getElementById('btn-xls').hidden = false;

        } else {
                document.getElementById('btn-xls').hidden = true;

        }
});

    $('#btn-xls').on('click', function(){
             alert('i am here')
             (...)
                };
        });
```

Comment: this looks fine. do you have any errors in your console window?

Comment: If useing Jquery I'd recommend using `.show()` and `.hide()` and `display:none;` instead of the hidden attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hidden attribute from `btn-xls`

```
<button id='btn-plot' class='btn-dark'>Plot</button>
<button id='btn-xls' class='btn-dark' >Excel</button>
```

Update the Javascript

```
$('#btn-xls').hide();
$('#btn-plot').on('click', function(lista) {
        var lista = data['lista'].toString()
        if (lista.length != 0) {
                $('#btn-xls').show();

        } else {
                $('#btn-xls').hide();

        }
});

    $('#btn-xls').on('click', function(){
              alert('i am here')
             (...)
                }; 
        });
```